# Removing duplicate columns from pandas.read_csv()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

By default, [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) mangles duplicate CSV headers in the form of X, X.1, ..., X.N.

The flag `mangle_dupe_cols = False` returns:

`ValueError: Setting mangle_dupe_cols=False is not supported yet`

This to me seems foolish as to why you would allow a Boolean flag but disable the Boolean-ness...

Is there a way through the pandas API that is best suited for detecting/removing duplicate headers upon DataFrame initialization through the `read_csv()` method?

**Possible Solution (non-API)**:

```
headers = set(df.columns) # will include 'X' and 'X.1'
n = 0
unique = []
for i in range(len(headers)):
    d = 1
    if i != n:
        continue # skip dupes
    elif (headers[i] + '.' + str(d)) in headers:
        while True: # find next unique element
            d += 1
            n += 1
            if (headers[i] + '.' + str(d)) not in headers:
                break
    unique.append(headers[i])
    n += 1
```

Comment: Are you on the latest version? Otherwise, what do you want to do? Remove them or rename the columns?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I am on 0.22.0 and I want to do 2 things: detect dupes and remove columns of dupes. Once found I can easily manipulate the DataFrame. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid this entirely without post-processing, something like `df.remove_dupe_cols()`.

Comment: Hmm, something like `df[~df.columns.str.contains('.')]`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That assumes no other headers have a `'.'`.

Comment: Yes... yes it does. You should use DSM's answer otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

I might do something like

```
In [22]: df = pd.read_csv("dup.col")

In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
   A  A.1  B  C  C.1  C.2  D  E  C.3
0  1    2  3  4    5    6  7  8    9
1  1    2  3  4    5    6  7  8    9

In [24]: df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.replace("(\.\d+)$", "").duplicated()]
Out[24]: 
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  3  4  7  8
1  1  3  4  7  8
```

(With a little more uglification we could handle non-string columns as well, but maybe YAGNI.)

Comment: In my opinion this does not do what you would want/expect from mange_dupe_cols=False: This removes duplicate columns rather than just not adding the suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my one-liner, assume there is no dot character in your column names.

```
df = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.find('.') < 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the previous answers remove duplicate columns, this is not what I would want/expect from mangle_dupe_cols=False, rather I would want to just avoid the suffix and to keep the duplicate columns, for this you could use:

`df.columns = ~df.columns.str.replace("(\.\d+)$", "")`

after importing the dataframe.

But this only works if you only have a single header consisting of strings, otherwise you would have to do something more fancy.