# How to add a file name to a column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe created from several csv files. The csv files are all structured the same way, so I have the same column names over and over again. I want the column names to be expanded by the file names (which I have as a list) they come from.
From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179369/removing-duplicate-columns-from-pandas-read-csv) I know how to add a count to same name columns and I know how to rename columns. But I fail at bringing the right file name to the right column value.

That should be the relevant part of the code:

```py
for i in range(len(file_list)):
    data = pd.read_table(file_list[i], encoding='unicode_escape')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.drop(droplist, axis=1)
    main_dataframe = pd.concat([main_dataframe, df], axis=1)
```

Comment: Best would be to add the column name while creating the DataFrame, it would be great that you provide a small example of your format

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary in [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to generate a MultiIndex:

```
list_of_files = ['f1.csv', 'f2.csv']
pd.concat({f: pd.read_table(f, encoding='unicode_escape', sep=',')
           for f in list_of_files}, axis=1)
```

example:

```
# f1.csv
a,b
1,2
3,4

# f2.csv
a,b
5,6
7,8
```

output:

```
  f1.csv    f2.csv   
       a  b      a  b
0      1  2      5  6
1      3  4      7  8
```

Alternative using [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) in the list comprehension:

```
pd.concat([pd.read_table(f, encoding='unicode_escape', sep=',')
                   .add_prefix(f[:-3]) # add prefix without ".csv" extension
           for f in list_of_files], axis=1))
```

output:

```
   f1.a  f1.b  f2.a  f2.b
0     1     2     5     6
1     3     4     7     8
```